# JVM crash :- Problematic frame: # V [libjvm.so+0x546720]

Tags: jboss

Production server has gone down and the preliminary analysis find that it has encountered a JVM crash.  The jboss server log and GC log seems to be ok. And the jvm error log mention the “Problematic frame: # V  [libjvm.so+0x546720]”.

Configuration details:-

The server is 64 bit machine having 32 bit RHEL-5.2. 
JAVA : jdk1.6.0_11
In memory (RAM) : 2GB
Heap size of Java virtual machine is -Xmx1024m.

`An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x06546720, pid=5127, tid=1822063504

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (11.0-b16 mixed mode linux-x86)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0x546720]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

> Current thread (0x09a05400):  GCTaskThread [stack:
>   0x6c927000,0x6c9a8000] [id=5130]
>
> siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR),
>   si_addr=0x00000008
>
> Registers: EAX=0x00000008, EBX=0xa60239c0, ECX=0x0000000c,
>   EDX=0x0000000c ESP=0x6c9a6ea0, EBP=0x6c9a6f18, ESI=0x00003ece,
>   EDI=0xe2c30913 EIP=0x06546720, CR2=0x00000008, EFLAGS=0x00010202
>
> Top of Stack: (sp=0x6c9a6ea0) 0x6c9a6ea0:   004ac889 00000000 004b7ff4
>   6cb57c56 0x6c9a6eb0:   00000000 09a06300 00000400 1c00dc04 0x6c9a6ec0:
>   00a039c8 00000008 00000000 01505e98 0x6c9a6ed0:   09a06328 09a06328
>   ffffffff ffffffff 0x6c9a6ee0:   b3d06048 b3d0604c 6c9a6f18 0000000d
>   0x6c9a6ef0:   b3d28450 00001000 00000001 00000001 0x6c9a6f00:
>   a6026fc1 b3d05db8 b3d06048 b3d2861c 0x6c9a6f10:   00003ece 09a5fc40
>   6c9a6f58 065462c3
>
> Instructions: (pc=0x06546720) 0x06546710:   e0 01 84 c0 0f 84 16 05 00
>   00 8b 45 ac 83 e0 fd 0x06546720:   8b 00 c1 e8 03 83 e0 0f 3b 05 cc 28
>   6b 06 0f 8d
>
> Stack: [0x6c927000,0x6c9a8000],  sp=0x6c9a6ea0,  free space=511k
>   Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code,
>   C=native code) V  [libjvm.so+0x546720] V  [libjvm.so+0x5462c3] V 
>   [libjvm.so+0x255c38] V  [libjvm.so+0x5493ba] V  [libjvm.so+0x32826b] V
>   [libjvm.so+0x506709] C  [libpthread.so.0+0x545b]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

> Java Threads: ( => current thread )   0x0a745000 JavaThread
>   "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9822,
>   stack(0x68fe4000,0x69005000)]   0x6ae59000 JavaThread "Java2D
>   Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5496,
>   stack(0x6c2a7000,0x6c2c8000)]   0x6b245800 JavaThread "TP-Monitor"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5493, stack(0x69ca6000,0x69cc7000)]
>   0x6b244000 JavaThread "TP-Processor4" daemon [_thread_in_native,
>   id=5492, stack(0x69cc7000,0x69ce8000)]   0x6b276c00 JavaThread
>   "TP-Processor3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5491,
>   stack(0x69ce8000,0x69d09000)]   0x6b276800 JavaThread "TP-Processor2"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5490, stack(0x69d09000,0x69d2a000)]
>   0x6b276000 JavaThread "TP-Processor1" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=5489, stack(0x69d2a000,0x69d4b000)]   0x0ad39800 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Monitor" [_thread_blocked, id=5488,
>   stack(0x69d4b000,0x69d6c000)]   0x0ad38400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor25" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5487,
>   stack(0x69d6c000,0x69d8d000)]   0x0bd06c00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5486,
>   stack(0x69d8d000,0x69dae000)]   0x0bd05400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5485,
>   stack(0x69dae000,0x69dcf000)]   0x0bd03c00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5484,
>   stack(0x69dcf000,0x69df0000)]   0x0bd02400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor21" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5483,
>   stack(0x69df0000,0x69e11000)]   0x0bd00c00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor20" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5482,
>   stack(0x69e11000,0x69e32000)]   0x0bcff400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor19" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5481,
>   stack(0x69e32000,0x69e53000)]   0x0bcfa800 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5480,
>   stack(0x69e53000,0x69e74000)]   0x0bcf9000 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5479,
>   stack(0x69e74000,0x69e95000)]   0x0aaa8400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5478,
>   stack(0x69e95000,0x69eb6000)]   0x0aaa6c00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5477,
>   stack(0x69eb6000,0x69ed7000)]   0x0aaa2400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5476,
>   stack(0x69ed7000,0x69ef8000)]   0x0a371400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5475,
>   stack(0x69ef8000,0x69f19000)]   0x0a370000 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5474,
>   stack(0x69f19000,0x69f3a000)]   0x0bd26c00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5473,
>   stack(0x69f3a000,0x69f5b000)]   0x0a93bc00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5472,
>   stack(0x69f5b000,0x69f7c000)]   0x0a93a400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5471,
>   stack(0x69f7c000,0x69f9d000)]   0x0a9e1c00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5470,
>   stack(0x69f9d000,0x69fbe000)]   0x0aa7bc00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5469,
>   stack(0x69fbe000,0x69fdf000)]   0x0a213c00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5468,
>   stack(0x69fdf000,0x6a000000)]   0x0aa0a400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5467,
>   stack(0x6a519000,0x6a53a000)]   0x0aa09400 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5466,
>   stack(0x6a53a000,0x6a55b000)]   0x0a5d2000 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5465,
>   stack(0x6a55b000,0x6a57c000)]   0x0a10bc00 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5464,
>   stack(0x6a57c000,0x6a59d000)]   0x09d72800 JavaThread
>   "http-0.0.0.0-8080-Processor1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5463,
>   stack(0x6a59d000,0x6a5be000)]   0x0a006c00 JavaThread
>   "JBossLifeThread" [_thread_blocked, id=5462,
>   stack(0x6a5be000,0x6a5df000)]   0x6b652400 JavaThread "Timer-4" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5461, stack(0x6a5df000,0x6a600000)]   0x0a45f400
>   JavaThread "TestScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked,
>   id=5460, stack(0x6a832000,0x6a853000)]   0x0a542c00 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-11" [_thread_blocked, id=5459,
>   stack(0x6a853000,0x6a874000)]   0x09fe9000 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=5458,
>   stack(0x6a874000,0x6a895000)]   0x0a3c8000 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=5457,
>   stack(0x6a895000,0x6a8b6000)]   0x0b27d800 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=5456,
>   stack(0x6a8b6000,0x6a8d7000)]   0x0bc9e800 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=5455,
>   stack(0x6a8d7000,0x6a8f8000)]   0x0a595000 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=5454,
>   stack(0x6a8f8000,0x6a919000)]   0x0abe7c00 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=5453,
>   stack(0x6a919000,0x6a93a000)]   0x0a1be400 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=5452,
>   stack(0x6a93a000,0x6a95b000)]   0x0a996c00 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=5451,
>   stack(0x6a95b000,0x6a97c000)]   0x0abea400 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=5450,
>   stack(0x6a97c000,0x6a99d000)]   0x0a5f7800 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5449,
>   stack(0x6a99d000,0x6a9be000)]   0x0a5f7400 JavaThread
>   "TestScheduler_Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=5448,
>   stack(0x6a9be000,0x6a9df000)]   0x0a2c1c00 JavaThread "Thread-12"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5447, stack(0x6a9df000,0x6aa00000)]
>   0x0a85cc00 JavaThread "Thread-11" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5446,
>   stack(0x6ab19000,0x6ab3a000)]   0x0a7cb800 JavaThread
>   "ElementEventQueue.QProcessor-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5445,
>   stack(0x6ab5b000,0x6ab7c000)]   0x0a504800 JavaThread "Thread-9"
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5442, stack(0x6ab3a000,0x6ab5b000)]   0x0ad5c400
>   JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5437,
>   stack(0x6ab7c000,0x6ab9d000)]   0x0b284000 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5436, stack(0x6ab9d000,0x6abbe000)]   0x0aef7c00
>   JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=5435,
>   stack(0x6abbe000,0x6abdf000)]   0x0a1dd400 JavaThread "Thread-4"
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5434, stack(0x6b06d000,0x6b08e000)]   0x0a7df400
>   JavaThread "Connection Consumer for dest
>   Subscription[subId=-2147483648connection=ConnectionToken:ID:2/b744868be8f2f16c9ebefdb987f81c71
>   destination=TOPIC.MastersSubscriberMDB messageSelector=null Local
>   Create] id=2" [_thread_blocked, id=5433, stack(0x6b08e000,0x6b0af000)]
>   0x0b26fc00 JavaThread "Connection Consumer for dest
>   Subscription[subId=-2147483648connection=ConnectionToken:ID:1/fcba95a2a4e911261ee0d2731536dba2
>   destination=TOPIC.EPrescriptionMDB messageSelector=null Local Create]
>   id=1" [_thread_blocked, id=5432, stack(0x6b0af000,0x6b0d0000)]
>   0x6b62f000 JavaThread "UILServerILService Accept Thread"
>   [_thread_in_native, id=5431, stack(0x6b35b000,0x6b37c000)]
>   0x6b1e8400 JavaThread "JCA PoolFiller" [_thread_blocked, id=5430,
>   stack(0x6b37c000,0x6b39d000)]   0x6bbf4400 JavaThread "IdleRemover"
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5429, stack(0x6b39d000,0x6b3be000)]   0x6b6aec00
>   JavaThread "TimeoutFactory" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5428,
>   stack(0x6b3be000,0x6b3df000)]   0x6bc8f400 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5427, stack(0x6abdf000,0x6ac00000)]   0x6bccd400
>   JavaThread "JBossMQ Cache Reference Softner" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=5426, stack(0x6a800000,0x6a821000)]   0x0a514400 JavaThread "HSQLDB
>   Timer @1ab5dae" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5424,
>   stack(0x6b3df000,0x6b400000)]   0x0a411400 JavaThread
>   "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]" daemon
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5422, stack(0x6b788000,0x6b7a9000)]   0x09f58400
>   JavaThread "PooledInvokerAcceptor#0-4445" [_thread_in_native, id=5421,
>   stack(0x6b7f8000,0x6b819000)]   0x09f59000 JavaThread "RMI TCP
>   Accept-4444" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5420,
>   stack(0x6b819000,0x6b83a000)]   0x09f46800 JavaThread
>   "ClassLoadingPool(2)-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5419,
>   stack(0x6b83a000,0x6b85b000)]   0x09f3b000 JavaThread "JBoss System
>   Threads(1)-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5418,
>   stack(0x6b85b000,0x6b87c000)]   0x09f87400 JavaThread "GC Daemon"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5417, stack(0x6b87c000,0x6b89d000)]
>   0x09f88c00 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=5416,
>   stack(0x6b89d000,0x6b8be000)]   0x09f88400 JavaThread "RMI TCP
>   Accept-1098" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5415,
>   stack(0x6b8be000,0x6b8df000)]   0x09f78c00 JavaThread "ScannerThread"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5414, stack(0x6b8df000,0x6b900000)]
>   0x09f3e800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5413,
>   stack(0x6ba39000,0x6ba5a000)]   0x099fcc00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM"
>   [_thread_blocked, id=5128, stack(0xb7f24000,0xb7f45000)]   0x09a9f000
>   JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5137,
>   stack(0x6c349000,0x6c36a000)]   0x09a9d400 JavaThread
>   "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5136,
>   stack(0x6c36a000,0x6c3eb000)]   0x09a9a400 JavaThread
>   "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5135,
>   stack(0x6c3eb000,0x6c46c000)]   0x09a98c00 JavaThread "Signal
>   Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5134,
>   stack(0x6c46c000,0x6c48d000)]   0x09a85c00 JavaThread "Finalizer"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5133, stack(0x6c68d000,0x6c6ae000)]
>   0x09a84400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=5132, stack(0x6c6ae000,0x6c6cf000)]

Other Threads:

> 0x09a80c00 VMThread [stack: 0x6c6cf000,0x6c750000] [id=5131]
>   0x09aa1000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x6c2c8000,0x6c349000] [id=5138]
>
> =>0x09a05400 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x6c927000,0x6c9a8000] [id=5130]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

> VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
>   [0x099faff8] UNKNOWN - owner thread: 0x09a80c00 [0x099fb408] UNKNOWN -
>   owner thread: 0x0bd03c00
>
> Heap  PSYoungGen      total 328704K, used 313529K [0x9f8b0000,
>   0xb4e00000, 0xb4e00000)   eden space 307904K, 100% used
>   [0x9f8b0000,0xb2560000,0xb2560000)   from space 20800K, 27% used
>   [0xb2560000,0xb2ade6b0,0xb39b0000)   to   space 20352K, 25% used
>   [0xb3a20000,0xb3f2e800,0xb4e00000)  PSOldGen        total 699072K,
>   used 489011K [0x74e00000, 0x9f8b0000, 0x9f8b0000)   object space
>   699072K, 69% used [0x74e00000,0x92b8cca8,0x9f8b0000)  PSPermGen
>   total 131072K, used 102017K [0x6ce00000, 0x74e00000, 0x74e00000)
>   object space 131072K, 77% used [0x6ce00000,0x731a0488,0x74e00000)

Dynamic libraries:

> 00312000-0032c000 r-xp 00000000 03:03 20776307   /lib/ld-2.5.so
>   0032c000-0032d000 r-xp 00019000 03:03 20776307   /lib/ld-2.5.so
>   0032d000-0032e000 rwxp 0001a000 03:03 20776307   /lib/ld-2.5.so
>   00330000-0046d000 r-xp 00000000 03:03 20776308   /lib/libc-2.5.so
>   0046d000-0046f000 r-xp 0013d000 03:03 20776308   /lib/libc-2.5.so
>   0046f000-00470000 rwxp 0013f000 03:03 20776308   /lib/libc-2.5.so
>   00470000-00473000 rwxp 00470000 00:00 0  00475000-0049a000 r-xp
>   00000000 03:03 20776309   /lib/libm-2.5.so 0049a000-0049b000 r-xp
>   00024000 03:03 20776309   /lib/libm-2.5.so 0049b000-0049c000 rwxp
>   00025000 03:03 20776309   /lib/libm-2.5.so 0049e000-004a0000 r-xp
>   00000000 03:03 20776314   /lib/libdl-2.5.so 004a0000-004a1000 r-xp
>   00001000 03:03 20776314   /lib/libdl-2.5.so 004a1000-004a2000 rwxp
>   00002000 03:03 20776314   /lib/libdl-2.5.so 004a4000-004b7000 r-xp
>   00000000 03:03 20776311   /lib/libpthread-2.5.so 004b7000-004b8000
>   r-xp 00012000 03:03 20776311   /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
>   004b8000-004b9000 rwxp 00013000 03:03 20776311
>   /lib/libpthread-2.5.so 004b9000-004bb000 rwxp 004b9000 00:00 0 
>   008da000-008e1000 r-xp 00000000 03:03 20776312   /lib/librt-2.5.so
>   008e1000-008e2000 r-xp 00006000 03:03 20776312   /lib/librt-2.5.so
>   008e2000-008e3000 rwxp 00007000 03:03 20776312   /lib/librt-2.5.so
>   008eb000-008fa000 r-xp 00000000 03:03 20776327   /lib/libresolv-2.5.so
>   008fa000-008fb000 r-xp 0000e000 03:03 20776327   /lib/libresolv-2.5.so
>   008fb000-008fc000 rwxp 0000f000 03:03 20776327   /lib/libresolv-2.5.so
>   008fc000-008fe000 rwxp 008fc000 00:00 0  00c74000-00c87000 r-xp
>   00000000 03:03 20776313   /lib/libnsl-2.5.so 00c87000-00c88000 r-xp
>   00012000 03:03 20776313   /lib/libnsl-2.5.so 00c88000-00c89000 rwxp
>   00013000 03:03 20776313   /lib/libnsl-2.5.so 00c89000-00c8b000 rwxp
>   00c89000 00:00 0  06000000-06676000 r-xp 00000000 03:03 4620339
>   /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so
>   06676000-066bb000 rwxp 00675000 03:03 4620339
>   /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so
>   066bb000-06add000 rwxp 066bb000 00:00 0  08048000-08052000 r-xp
>   00000000 03:03 4685976    /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java
>   08052000-08053000 rwxp 00009000 03:03 4685976
>   /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_11/bin/java 099f7000-0bd51000 rwxp 099f7000
>   00:00 0  68c00000-68cd8000 rwxp 68c00000 00:00 0  68cd8000-68d00000
>   --xp 68cd8000 00:00 0  68e00000-68efc000 rwxp 68e00000 00:00 0  68efc000-68f00000 --xp 68efc000 00:00 0  68fe4000-68fe7000 --xp
>   68fe4000 00:00 0  68fe7000-69005000 rwxp 68fe7000 00:00 0 
>   69005000-69008000 rwxp 69005000 00:00 0  69008000-69026000 rwxp
>   69008000 00:00 0  69026000-69045000 r-xs 00000000 03:03 4166654
>   /usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/courb.pfa 69045000-69059000 r-xs 00000000
>   03:03 4166663    /usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1/l047016t.pfa
>   ............... b7f59000-b7f5a000 rwxp b7f59000 00:00 0 
>   b7f5a000-b7f5b000 --xp b7f5a000 00:00 0  b7f5b000-b7f5c000 rwxp
>   b7f5b000 00:00 0  b7f5c000-b7f5d000 r-xp b7f5c000 00:00 0
>   [vdso] bfb27000-bfb3d000 rwxp bfb27000 00:00 0          [stack]

VM Arguments:

> jvm_args: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -Xss128k
>   -Dsalmon.props.path=/usr/local/jboss/jboss-3.2.7/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat50.sar/salmonprops
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -verbose:gc -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Xloggc:/usr/local/jboss/jboss-3.2.7/server/default/log/gclog.log -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/jboss/jboss-3.2.7/lib/endorsed  java_command: org.jboss.Main Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:

> PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/jboss/bin
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/i386:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/../lib/i386
>   SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:

> SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x606fd0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x606fd0],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGFPE:
>   [libjvm.so+0x504690], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
>   SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x504690], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x504690],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGILL:
>   [libjvm.so+0x504690], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
>   SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000 SIGUSR2:
>   [libjvm.so+0x506b60], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
>   SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x506900], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff,
>   sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000,
>   sa_flags=0x00000000 SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x506900],
>   sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004 SIGQUIT:
>   [libjvm.so+0x506900], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga)

uname:Linux 2.6.18-92.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 29 13:16:12 EDT 2008 i686
libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 32601, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:0.10 0.06 0.02

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2065048k(434208k free), swap 4192956k(4192956k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (11.0-b16) for linux-x86 JRE (1.6.0_11-b03), built on Nov 10 2008 01:21:35 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.1-7a (J2SE release)

time: Tue Jun 14 15:50:47 2011
elapsed time: 17909 seconds`

Comment: Ok, your production server crashed. What do you want from us?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're running you're JVM with a 2GB heap on a machine with about 2GB ram, and the heap isn't the only thing in the JVM (or system for that matter) using memory. Might it be possible that a heap access is causing a page fault (forcing it to go into swap)? I wouldn't expect the JVM to puke in that scenario, but I suppose it's possible.

EDIT: Sorry, misread that. 1GB heap, 2GB ram. I guess I have no idea, then.

Answer (score -3):

Try to check the hardware in the system. Maybe Memory has gone old.
First benchmark the hardware (use sysbench incase of linux).
Just change the memory, it will work fine.